# How to retrieve cookies in express via browser?

Tags: express, cookies, backend

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days now, but to no avail.  I'm using cookie-parser and have followed the code of other people but it's still not working. It works perfectly in postman, but not on the browser. The browser I'm currently using is google chrome, but I've also tested it on microsoft edge which gives the same result.

```
app.get('/testCookie',(req,res) => {
    res.cookie('username','flavio');
    res.json({message:req.cookies});
})
```

// frontend

```
 const data = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/testCookie');
 console.log(data); // returns {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asper, I understand you want to set cookies and access it in the client-side, then this might help you.
Server-side

```
 const cookieConfig = {
 httpOnly: false,
 maxAge: 315569260000,//age of cookie any value possible
 }


 app.get('/testCookie',(req,res) => {
  res.cookie('username','flavio',cookieConfig);
 })
```

Client side

```
 let data = document.cookie
            .split('; ')
            .find(row => row.startsWith('username'))
            .split('=')[1];
 console.log(data)
```